# How to scroll particular div from page using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, scroll

I have a page with multiple sections(divs). In that only one div is scrollable, not the whole page. So I can scroll that particular div using Selenium? Javascript will also work if possible, so I will execute that script.

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476847/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory)

In this post, you can see 2nd part of the question(code) is scrollable so I want to scroll only that code part rather than the whole page.

Thank you

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @cruisepandey could you please updated the post.

Comment: What do you mean by update the POST ?

Comment: I meant to say that I have updated the description of my query. Please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: @cruisepandey do you know how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the selenium, I am not able to scroll. But through Javascript, I made one script and execute that script with JavascriptExecutor.

Sometimes script not running on the first try so try to put it into a loop and do retry.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
                
String js = "(document.evaluate('XPATH_OF_ELEMENT', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue).scrollBy(0,10000)";
                
System.out.println(js);

jse.executeScript(js);
```